# How to fetch records from a Oracle table using SQL based on some condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Please refer attached ER diagram.

I need to write a SQL query to fetch records from 2 main tables (Table A and Table B) based on a condition.

Condition is for a given Application (`APP_ID`) :

- if the Table A `Case_Status` is True (if `Case_Status` = '00') then fetch all the Table A details (like `First_name`, `Last_name`) along with details from   Table B (i.e. `Person_name`, `comments` from Table B) corresponding to that application
- otherwise just fetch application details from Table A only (`First_name`, `Last_name` etc)

Table C is just a master table that stores the status code as 'True' or 'False' in its description Column (Status_Id->00, means True and Status_Id->01 means False).

Please suggest me on this. I want to join both columns and bring data but I can't write the condition correctly.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack...

```
select a.app_id
        , a.case_status
        , a.first_name
        , a.last_name
        , b.description
        , b.person_name
        , b.comments
from tableA a
left join tableB b
on a.app_id = b.app_id
and a.case_status = '00'
```

... but it will return all the values in `tableA`, plus matching values from `tableB` when the status is correct.